# I can't buy the property in Falkreath

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I'm having trouble buying the land in Falkreath. I've already received the letter from Siddgeir but he won't show the dialog option for purchasing land. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You don't buy [the house](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lakeview_Manor) from the jarl, you buy it from his steward. Additionally, when Siddgeir is jarl, you have to have complete the quest [Kill the Bandit Leader](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Kill_the_Bandit_Leader_(Jarl)) from him.

Once you have done so, his steward will let you purchase the land.

Comment: hey guys I just figured out that im not allowed to buy property in falkreath vause I already killed helvard before I got the dlc sooo thanks Josh Petrie for the link

Comment: @miiraksbane if you didn't side with the civil war, join the stormcloaks to replace the jarl and  steward and you can buy the land.

Answer (score 0):

You have to talk to the steward if you want this house. If it still doesn't have the option, you might have:

> Killed Helvard for the Dark Brotherhood

this will make Siddgeir's disposition low and you won't be able to buy it since he hates you. The only way to fix this is side with the Stormcloaks in the Civil War and complete the questline so the Jarl and Steward will be replaced and you can assist the people and then talk to them about the house.